# Finding customers with identical orders

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to find customers who have made identical orders.  (Using T-SQL)

**Order**

```
OrderID Customerer  
1   2   
2   5   
3   6   
4   2   
5   4   
6   6   
7   8
```

**OrderLine**

```
OrderLineID OrderID OrderDate   OrderType   Quantity    Reference  
1   1   01/01/2011  1   1   Coca Cola  
2   1   01/01/2011  1   3   Tea  
3   2   02/02/2011  2   1   Coffee  
4   2   02/02/2011  2   2   Solo  
5   2   03/02/2011  1   1   Soda  
6   3   03/02/2011  1   3   Tea  
7   3   03/02/2011  1   1   Coca Cola  
8   4   05/06/2011  1   1   Beer  
9   5   06/06/2011  2   1   Tea  
10  5   06/06/2011  2   1   Coca Cola  
11  6   07/07/2011  1   1   Coffee  
12  6   07/07/2011  1   2   Solo  
13  6   07/07/2011  1   1   Soda  
14  6   07/07/2011  1   1   Beer  
15  7   08/08/2011  1   1   Beer
```

Here orders with OrderID 1 and 3 are considered to be identical because the number for orderlines, "Quantity" and "Reference" are identical on both orders. Meaning that customer 2 and 6 have placed identical orders.

Order 5 are not identical to order 1 and 3 because Quantity differ.

Order 2 are not identical to order 6 because orderlines differ.

Order 4 and 7 are also identical.

I am searching for a ressult like this:

**IdenticalOrders**

```
OrderID CustomeerID  
1   2  
3   6  
4   2  
7   8
```

It seems like an easy task, but I just can't understand where to start.
(I am still new to t-sql :-) )

Comment: The result as you sketch it gives you any order that is identical to any other order, but you won't know which is the matching order

Comment: This is a variant of relational division.

Comment: I agree with devio. The resulting information is not very useful at all, especially if there are more than 2 matching orders. I've come up with a variation of Martin Smith's second option (which I think is brilliant). I will post it shortly.

Comment: I would also mention that since your business logic would presuppose that an identical order is impossible, then returning more than 1 matching invoice is a little overkill since there should only ever be one.

Comment: Thanks all for your comments. Thank JohnD for editing my "messy" question :-)

Comment: Please mark an answer as correct if any of them has helped you at all as courtesy to the contributors and also as a way of helping others who are going to have this problem in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an extension of Martin's second suggestion. This will show all matching combinations without any repetitions.

```
;With FmtOL(customer, orderid, complete_order) as
(            
SELECT  customer, orderid, complete_order
     FROM    Order O
                    cross apply ( SELECT    CAST(Quantity AS VARCHAR(30))
                                            + '~' + Reference + '~~'
                                  FROM      OrderLine OL
                                  WHERE     OL.OrderID = O.OrderID
                                  ORDER BY  Reference ,
                                            Quantity
                                FOR
                                  XML PATH('')
                                ) T ( complete_order )
)
SELECT  T1.OrderId, 
        T1.Customer,
        STUFF(C1.a, 1, 2, '') as [SameAs]
FROM    FmtOL T1
Cross apply ( SELECT '; ' + 'Customer ' + Cast(T2.Customer as varchar(30)) 
                  + '''s order ' + Cast(T2.OrderID as varchar(30))
                 FROM   FmtOL T2
                 WHERE  T1.Customer < T2.Customer
                   AND T1.OrderId < T2.OrderId
                   AND T1.complete_order = T2.complete_order
                 order by ';' + Cast(T2.Customer as varchar(30)) 
                    + '''s order ' + Cast(T2.OrderID as varchar(30))
                    , t2.orderid
                 for xml path('')
             ) C1 (a)
  where C1.a is not null
```

Results should look like this:

```
OrderId Customer SameAs 
1       2        Customer 6's order 3 
4       2        Customer 8's order 7
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way.

```
SELECT  O1.OrderID ,
        O1.Customer ,
        O2.OrderID ,
        O2.Customer
FROM    [Order] O1
        JOIN [Order] O2 ON O1.OrderID < O2.OrderID
                           AND O1.Customer <> O2.Customer
WHERE   NOT EXISTS ( SELECT Quantity ,
                            Reference
                     FROM   OrderLine
                     WHERE  O1.OrderID = OrderLine.OrderID
                     EXCEPT
                     SELECT Quantity ,
                            Reference
                     FROM   OrderLine
                     WHERE  O2.OrderID = OrderLine.OrderID )
        AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT Quantity ,
                                Reference
                         FROM   OrderLine
                         WHERE  O2.OrderID = OrderLine.OrderID
                         EXCEPT
                         SELECT Quantity ,
                                Reference
                         FROM   OrderLine
                         WHERE  O1.OrderID = OrderLine.OrderID )
```

You can also use `XML PATH` to simulate `GROUP_CONCAT` then `JOIN` the two result sets

```
DECLARE @T TABLE
    (
      OrderId INT PRIMARY KEY,
      Customer INT ,
      complete_order VARCHAR(MAX)
    )  

    INSERT  INTO @T
            SELECT  *
            FROM    [Order] O
                    CROSS APPLY ( SELECT    CAST(Quantity AS VARCHAR(30))
                                            + '~' + Reference + '~~'
                                  FROM      OrderLine OL
                                  WHERE     OL.OrderID = O.OrderID
                                  ORDER BY  Reference ,
                                            Quantity
                                FOR
                                  XML PATH('')
                                ) T ( complete_order )

SELECT  T1.OrderId, 
        T1.Customer
FROM    @T T1
WHERE   EXISTS ( SELECT *
                 FROM   @T T2
                 WHERE  T1.Customer <> T2.Customer
                        AND T1.OrderId <> T2.OrderId
                        AND T1.complete_order = T2.complete_order )
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the most simple approach.

```
-- sample table
create table x
    (
         LineId int identity(1, 1)
        ,InvoiceFk int
        ,ProductFk int
        ,Quantity int
    )

-- sample data
insert into x 
(InvoiceFk, ProductFk, Quantity) values
     (11, 1, 1)
    ,(11, 2, 1)
    ,(11, 3, 1)
    ,(12, 1, 2)
    ,(12, 2, 2)
    ,(12, 3, 2)
    ,(13, 1, 3)
    ,(13, 2, 3)
    ,(13, 3, 3)

-- your order, probably from a parameter
declare @order table
    (
         InvoiceFk int
        ,ProductFk int
        ,Quantity int
    )
insert into @order
(InvoiceFk, ProductFk, Quantity) values
     (14, 1, 1) -- duplicate invoice 11
    ,(14, 2, 1)
    ,(14, 3, 1)

-- your order unique checksum
declare @orderCheck int
select @orderCheck = checksum_agg(checksum(ProductFk, Quantity))
from @order

-- test your order in existing data
declare @match int
select @match = 
    (
        select TOP 1 InvoiceFk from
        (
            select
                 InvoiceFk
                ,checksum_agg(Col1) as Col2
            from
                (
                select 
                     InvoiceFk
                    ,checksum(productfk, quantity) as Col1
                from x
                ) as T1
            group by
                InvoiceFk
        ) as T2
        where 
            T2.Col2 = @orderCheck
    )


-- evaluate if your order is unique or not
if (@match is not null)
begin
    print 'Identical to invoice: ' + Str(@match);
end
else
begin
    print 'Order is unique';
end

-- clean up sample table
drop table x
```

Best of luck!

Comment: Result is `Identical to invoice:         11`

Comment: There is always an issue of performance to consider with any SQL activity. Because of your stated requirements, I recommend you use my code to generate the Invoice checksum and store that value in the Invoices table. This way you do not need to recalculate it every time you try to submit an order. All you need to do is a quick WHERE against Invoices.ItemsCheckSum column (which will be far more efficient). But that's just a recommendation; you are your own developer. My code works without such a column, too.

Comment: Thanks :-) I'll look into this. I'll test both solutions.

Comment: I have finaly tested everything and vent with a  @Jerry Nixon's answer.

Comment: and @James Jiao answer.  (I had two problems, one answer gave me the solution that I could adapt to one problem, and the other answer gave solution for another problem.) So since I can only select one "answer" I will have to go with James Jiao. I learned most from it, and it was easy to understand. But again: Thanks to everyone :-)