# Finding matching sets

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Considering these tables

```
create table orders
(orderid int primary key)

create table orderlines
(orderid int foreign key (orderid) references orders,
 product nvarchar(max))
```

With data like this

```
 insert into orders values (1)
 insert into orders values (2)
 insert into orders values (3)
 insert into orders values (4)
 insert into orders values (5)
 insert into orders values (6)


 insert into orderlines values (3, 'p1')
 insert into orderlines values (3, 'p2')
 insert into orderlines values (4, 'p1')
 insert into orderlines values (4, 'p2')
 insert into orderlines values (5, 'p1')
 insert into orderlines values (5, 'p3')
 insert into orderlines values (6, 'p1')
```

What query would give me the pairs of orders that have exactly the same products on their orderlines?

Expected output

```
orderid     orderid
----------- -----------
1           2
3           4
```

Because orders 1 and 2 both have no orderlines
and orders 3 and 4 have exactly the same set of products (p1,p2)

Things to consider:

- Select each pair only once (doable by keeping left orderid < right orderid for each pair)
- Also include pairs that have no orderlines at all (orders 1 and 2)
- Include only those orders having exactly the same products in their orderlines (orders 3 and 4)

Weapon of choice: t-sql / sqlserver 2008

Comment: I and 2 dont have and productid so only they are same??

Comment: what is the result if ordeline is (1,2)(2,2)(3,2)

Comment: (1,'p1')(2,'p1')(3,'p1') would output three lines: 1-2, 2-3 and 1-3

Comment: your sample output has (1,2) how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By asking the question I now found an answer by looking through the related questions: 
[Finding customers with identical orders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7114519/finding-customers-with-identical-orders?rq=1)

```
SELECT  O1.OrderID ,
        O2.OrderID 
FROM    [Orders] O1
        JOIN [Orders] O2 ON O1.OrderID < O2.OrderID
WHERE   NOT EXISTS ( SELECT productid 
                     FROM   OrderLines
                     WHERE  O1.OrderID = OrderLines.OrderID
                     EXCEPT
                     SELECT productid
                     FROM   OrderLines
                     WHERE  O2.OrderID = OrderLines.OrderID )
        AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT productid 
                     FROM   OrderLines
                     WHERE  O2.OrderID = OrderLines.OrderID
                     EXCEPT
                     SELECT productid
                     FROM   OrderLines
                     WHERE  O1.OrderID = OrderLines.OrderID )
```